# .NET MAUI crashes on Android with error 'Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.iOS ...'

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a .NET Maui project on my PC Working in VS 2022 v17.8.3, Xamarin 17.8.0.156 and net7.0. I'm connected to a Mac with VS v17.6, XCode v15.2. I can run the iOS simulator on my PC just fine however when targeting the Android simulator on my PC it crashes shortly after deploying to it. My splash screen shows but when the App exits the `public App(){InitializeComponent();}` method it crashes with this error:
[image]

In researching this error (not many results) everyone else seems to get it when trying to deploy to an iOS simulator or device. I've tried their solutions which generally are deleting Temp folders & files but to no avail.
I'm wondering if it is the version of the file. Is it tied to my version of VS or Xamarin and since it is ver 16 and my VS & Xamarin are 17? I'm grasping at straws. So any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to repair the Visual Studio? It would take a few hours to get it done.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT I have not, however I have a Xamarin project that runs on the same PC and it deploys for debug just fine. FYI-the MAUI project is a conversion of the Xamarin project and it had deployed in the past. But all of a sudden it stopped deploying.

Comment: 1. What if you edit the csproj file and then remove iOS from the target frameworks: see [this link](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10626#issuecomment-1277112693) 2. Also, it's suggested to report Visual Studio tooling issues is via Visual Studio's "Report a Problem" menu and then follow them on the developer community site. Please see [How to report a problem with Visual Studio - Visual Studio | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022&viewFallbackFrom=vs-201)